# T4 Template to generate Sql CE classes for WP7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-phone-7

Are there any T4 templates or a utility that can take a Entity Framework model and create the classes for a SQL CE db to be used on WP7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I use http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/

I think it is a shame there is not better tooling support provided.